# JS Tree doesn't get the right data due to a varaible from the SQL query used by the tree

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I am new to the platform and I'm not familiar with how I should describe better for everyone this problem but I hope that I will make it clear.
I am trying to make a website which includes a page with a "tree". This "tree" form will include boxes, folders and files. The tree is based on the "id" and "parent id" principle. I have also a input where I take a 21 characters string and search by that string in the database. Unfortunately it is not working with the variable, is working just if I place a value in the query or a variable already declared with the value.

I compared the value already declared with the one taken from the input and they are the same. I tried to encode the variable in utf8.

The query from fetch.php that doesn't load

```
$pr=$_GET['code'];
$pr2=utf8_encode_deep($pr);

     $sql=";with cte 
            as (select code128 as id,below as parent_id,comment as name, comment as text
            from hrdocs as h 
            where code128 = '$pr2'
            UNION ALL
            select h.code128, h.below, h.comment, h.comment
            from hrdocs as h 
            join cte 
            on h.below = cte.id)
            select *
            from cte
            order by parent_id asc;";
```

The query from fetch.php that works:

```
$pr2='170720190945070507790';

     $sql=";with cte 
            as (select code128 as id,below as parent_id,comment as name, comment as text
            from hrdocs as h 
            where code128 = '$pr2'
            UNION ALL
            select h.code128, h.below, h.comment, h.comment
            from hrdocs as h 
            join cte 
            on h.below = cte.id)
            select *
            from cte
            order by parent_id asc;";
```

I want to be able to use that variable from input in order to have a tree just from the master type of box/folder/file that I am searching for.

Comment: so what is different with the passed in value?

Comment: This is the problem because everything looks the same, i made a echo for the query and in both cases the variable is replaced by the value and if copy that echoed query to SQL it runs ok

Comment: This is the view with the variable declared like "$pr2='170720190945070507790';" [working](https://imgur.com/a/679N9AG) And this one is if i am using the variable taken from input [not working](https://imgur.com/a/5qQ0MX7) Both should have the same result (treeview), and at the top you can see that the data generated is the same